# How To Add URL From Cloud Firestore Using Using url_launcher Package

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

I am creating a Card layout in Flutter using Cloud Firestore. The Card contains an image, two IconButtons and some text. I want the IconButtons to open URL links that I add as a string in Firebase. How do I do this with the url_launcher package? I tried replacing `const url = 'example.com';` inside the `_launchURL` function with `const url = record.url` but goth thrown an undefined error for `record`.

I am very new to development and Stackoverflow so if I can structure the question better please let me know. Thanks!

```
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              IconButton(
                icon: Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.youtube),
                onPressed: _launchURL(),
              ),
              IconButton(
                icon: Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.google),
                onPressed: _launchURL(),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          Container(
            child: Text(record.gameParagraph),
          ),
        ],
        ),

_launchURL() async {
  const url = 'example.com'; // URL to be added from Cloud Firestore
  if (await canLaunch(url)){
    await launch(url);
  } else {
    throw 'Could not launch $url';
  }
}

class Record {
  final String gameParagraph;
  final String url;
  final DocumentReference reference;

  Record.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map, {this.reference})
  : assert(map['gameParagraph'] != null),
    assert(map['url'] != null),
  gameParagraph = map['gameParagraph'],
  url = map['url'];

  Record.fromSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot snapshot)
  : this.fromMap(snapshot.data, reference: snapshot.reference);

  @override
  String toString() => "Record<$gameParagraph:$url>";

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add make `_launchURL()` to take a string value which will be your url `_launchURL(String url)` and then

```
 _launchURL(String url) async {

  if (await canLaunch(url)){
    await launch(url);
  } else {
    throw 'Could not launch $url';
  }
}
//
 IconButton(
         icon: Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.google),
          onPressed: (){    
              _launchURL(url:record.url),// or _launchURL(record.url)}
          ),
```